# How do I convert an Array of Promise to an Array of the values resolved from each Promise in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

This is what I was trying to serialize via `JSON.stringify(gamesList);`

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

The following is printed output of `console.log(gamesList);`
[image]

Here's part of my code:

```
let gamesList = [];
while (hasNextPage(true)) {
    let list = getGamesList();
    gamesList = gamesList.concat(list);
}

console.log(gamesList);
Promise.all(gamesList).then((value) => {
    saveAs(
        new Blob([JSON.stringify(gamesList)]),
        'Humble_Bundle_Games.json'
    );
});
```

I'm new to JS and this use of async code and Promise class. I don't really know why gamesList contains Promise objects since the func returns a list containing dictionaries / maps.
`getGamesList` is an async function
Reading the MDN JS docs, it looks like `Promise.all` is what I want, but idk how to access the resolved value within the resolved promise.

I'm using vanilla JS with one imported file, FileSaver.js

[full source code](https://github.com/jtara1/ExportHumbleBundleLibrary/tree/5e9c19b437b813f543c9c041aa0dd8a341c15040)

Comment: `saveAs(
        new Blob([JSON.stringify(value)]), ...` The array of values is called `value`, so use it instead of the array of Promises called `gamesList`.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that `getGamesList` function gets data from a web page and after that page is received you will know if it has a next page so `hasNextPage` can only know if there is a next page when `getGmesList` is finished?

Comment: @HMR yea that's what `getGamesList` does. `hasNextPage` just checks the buttons [1] [2] ... [25] and returns current page index !== last page index. The two functions are independent of each other but required the same webpage. Problem solved with @Kaiido reply and reading MDN docs more thoroughly.

Comment: Laxmukants answer doesn't require the result of getGamesList to know if there is a next page. Your code would probably a lot simpler if you map page data to URLs then map urls to promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gamesList` is array of promise. If you do `JSON.stringify(new Promise())` it will print `{}` as it is an object. `Promise.all` will take array of promises, it will resolve all promises and call callback of then method and pass the resolved values.

Your code will become

```
let gamesList = [];
while (hasNextPage(true)) {
    let list = getGamesList();
    gamesList = gamesList.concat(list);
}

console.log(gamesList);
Promise.all(gamesList).then((value) => {
    saveAs(
        value, // it contains array of all resolved values
        'Humble_Bundle_Games.json'
    );
});
```

> Just to understand concept of promises:

```js
var a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(10)
  }, 100)

})

var b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(20)
  }, 200)

});

var arr = [a, b];


Promise.all(arr).then(value => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) // It will print [{},{}]
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value)) // It will print [10,20]
})
```